# Can you print Java a variable using an escape sequence?

Tags: java

Is there a way to print a variable using an escape sequence, similar to in Swift (shown below)?

I`var variable = 0
print("The number \(variable) is cool!")`

And yes, i know there are other ways to accomplish the same goal, but i want to shorten the code and avoid monsters such as

```
String variable = "0";
System.out.print("The number" + variable + "is cool!");
```

I would also like to avoid having to parse everything for it to print different types

Comment: No, Java lacks string interpolation feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.print("The number " + variable + " is cool!");
```

or

```
System.out.printf("The number %s is cool!", variable );
```

or

```
System.out.printf(MessageFormat.format("The number {0} is cool!", variable));
```

more options than those are not possible until now...

Comment: You were missing the `f` on `printf`, and I thought mentioning [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) would be appropriate too.

Answer (score 0):

As of the current version of java string escape is not possible, you could however use the printf function which behaves as follows

```
System.out.printf("The number %d is cool!", variable);
```

The %d symbol tell the program to look for a variable that is an integer.
A complete list of the symbols can be found [here](http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet)